# SQL Join two query having different number of columns

Tags: sql, database, join

**First Query**:(I have added count(*) for simplification)

```
select count(*) from Sales_order_line sol
where
sol.grant_type_id is null
AND
 sol.quantity  - NVL ((SELECT SUM (salesorder15_.assigned_quantity) FROM license_link_sales_ord_ln salesorder15_  
 WHERE salesorder15_.sales_order_line_id = sol.ID),0) > 0;
```

**Second Query**:(I have added count(*) for simplification)

```
select count(*) from Sales_order_line sol
INNER JOIN license_link_sales_ord_ln sola
ON sol.id=sola.sales_order_line_id
where
sol.grant_type_id is null;
```

The first query returns **56119** and second one returns **362260**. I want to combine the queries which gives me **(56119 +362260)** as result.

Comment: So you want to `OR` these two queries. Are you sure the results are dijunct? If there is any `Sales_order_line` that is returned by *both* queries, the `OR` would return *less* rows.

Comment: Do you mean the Sum of 56119 + 362260 or literally "(56119 + 362260)"? Also what DBMS are you using?

Comment: The purpose is not to reduce rows . it should be able to fetch all the rows from first query as well as second query. the count(*) is just for simplification, it actually fetches a number of rows.

Comment: could you pls provide sample data and your expected output? i have really no idea what you try to achive

Comment: You can picture the query in this way:select 
sol.ID  , sol.sales_customer_name  ,sol.sales_customer_number  ,sol.sales_order_number 
from Sales_order_line sol
where
sol.grant_type_id is null
AND
 sol.quantity  - NVL ((SELECT SUM (salesorder15_.assigned_quantity) FROM license_link_sales_ord_ln salesorder15_  
 WHERE salesorder15_.sales_order_line_id = sol.ID),0) > 0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To union the queries together with different numbers of columns you need to fill the columns that are not the same (don't match in both queries) with null as shown below:

```
SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD, columnE
FROM Sales_order_line s
WHERE s.grant_type_id IS NULL
AND s.quantity  - NVL ((SELECT SUM (so.assigned_quantity) 
                        FROM license_link_sales_ord_ln so
                        WHERE so.sales_order_line_id = s.ID),0) > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC, null, null
FROM Sales_order_line s
INNER JOIN license_link_sales_ord_ln l ON s.id = l.sales_order_line_id
WHERE s.grant_type_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM Sales_order_line s
WHERE s.grant_type_id IS NULL
AND s.quantity  - NVL ((SELECT SUM (so.assigned_quantity) 
                        FROM license_link_sales_ord_ln so
                        WHERE so.sales_order_line_id = s.ID),0) > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*)
FROM Sales_order_line s
INNER JOIN license_link_sales_ord_ln l ON s.id = l.sales_order_line_id
WHERE s.grant_type_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: The problem is that both the queries returns different columns for eg first query returns 10 and second one returns 15.

Comment: Is there any other way how this can be achieved without the UNION ALL option. I was hoping for a change in query ,with some kind of join.

Comment: For extra columns use `null AS column name` to even them out